# How to have a "base" route for each route of a routing module in angular

Tags: angular, angular-router

I've a `auth` module, with several components: `login`, `signup`, `logout`.

I declare all the routes in a a routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { LoginComponent } from "./login/login.component";
import { SignupComponent } from "./signup/signup.component";
import { LogoutComponent } from "./logout/logout.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
      path: "auth/login",
      component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
      path: "auth/signup",
      component: SignupComponent
  },
  {
      path: "auth/logout",
      component: LogoutComponent
  },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule {}
```

but I feel that all those "auth" are quite redundant. Is there a way to indicate(even by the root app-routing module?) that all rules of this routing-module have this `auth` before?

**EDIT**
Here is my main module routing(at least one try):

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo:'/beers', pathMatch:'full' },
    { path: 'beers', loadChildren: './beers/beers.module#BeersModule'},
    { path: 'auth', loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule'},
];

export const AppRoutes: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled', enableTracing: true});
```

Comment: Can you add your `app-routing.module` code?

Comment: @peinearydevelopment I added my last try

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible, without your full code it is hard to advise you how specifically to achieve this, but you would do something like the following in your `app-routing.module`

```
[
      {
        path: '',
        component: App.AppComponent,
        children: [
          { path: 'auth', loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule' }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Then the routes in your  `auth.module` would look like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
      path: "login",
      component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
      path: "signup",
      component: SignupComponent
  },
  {
      path: "logout",
      component: LogoutComponent
  },
];
```

Comment: Okay, This was my first try, except that I was not having the path `auth` in a children of the empty path. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: in fact the issue that I've with your approach is that the empty path should redirect to  some other  path, and it appears that I cannot use "redirectTo" AND children inside of the empty path

Comment: I just tried this, without my redirectTo, and tried to navigate to /auth/login and I get this error: `ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'auth/login'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'auth/login'`.

How do you register the Routes of the auth.module? Maybe I've something wrong here?

Comment: Hard to say without having the code to look at. Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t1xghl) demonstrating the above approach. If this doesn't work for you, I suggest you create a StackBlitz of your own demonstrating the problem.